# Where to put documentation for a Kotlin file (not package, not module, not class)

Tags: kotlin, comments, kdoc

Where should I put a comment about a Kotlin source file?

Classes and other objects have KDoc:

```
/**
 * Summary
 *
 * Rest of documentation goes here.
 */
class A {
    ...
}
```

But where should I put something like this?

```
// This file contains constants shared between frontend and backend.
// Make sure not to use any JVM- or JS-specific import.
// ...
```

Before the `package` declaration? After it? Should I use KDoc comments / block comments / line comments?

Is there any established convention?

Comment: Also looking for this.  Respondents questioning its utility are missing an important use case: KTS self-contained script files, for which the package carries less importance and no other natural place to document the overall script exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file is not part of an API, therefore there is no place where you can put documentation for a file so that it will be picked by Dokka. You should use regular (not KDoc) comments for such documentation, and put it into a place where it will be good to find for human readers (most likely after the imports block), because the machines have no use for this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using copyright comment so you can put it before the `package` declaration

If you are using doc comment about information for your file you can put it after the `imports`

Comment: Do you mean `/** This file ... */` after the imports? Is this an established convention? Will this be picked up by KDoc tools? Wouldn't it be considered (by both machine and humans) as just a comment on the first declaration following it?